# How to calculate torque on a satellite?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, torque, satellites

Suppose we have two satellites $X$ and $Y$, orbiting the Earth. The orbital radius of satellite $X$ is four times that of satellite $Y$.

There is one question asking me to compare the torque on each satellite.

What I know about torque is that it is the product of force and perpendicular distance. However in this question, I don't know how to calculate the perpendicular, though I know that the force here is gravitational attraction.

Comment: What is the question?  What torque are you thinking about?

Comment: Hint: there is only one force acting on the satellites due to the planet, and it is not a contact force. So, to help you answer @garyp question how do you get a torque from a non-contact fores acting over a distance? (This behavior has a name.)

Comment: @dmckee: Sorry, but I have no idea on what torque is produced by a non-contact force.

Comment: @Idontknow This question sounds like the sort of thing that would be assigned in a class or given in a text as an exercise for the student. In either of those contexts the relevant physics would have been discussed shortly before the question was posed. That's at least part of why people are ignoring it: we've no idea what is preventing you from simply applying the physics involved to this particular situation. Most of the users on [physics.se] ***really*** don't want to be thought of as a resource you can call on to avoid reading prepared material (for a class or otherwise).